# Modifying a primary key to auto-increment from a set value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, create-table, alter-table

I have the following MYSQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE students MODIFY studentID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT = 20;
```

StudentID already exists and is primary key. I want to edit it to autoincrement from 20. However, I am getting a red line on the equals sign in mySQL Workbench and the message

```
= is not valid in this position, expecting EOF.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
ALTER TABLE students AUTO_INCREMENT = 20;
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. Still allowed me to add a student at with an ID of 0

Comment: @JeremyRenner2: see [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a7844b868bd3bc03614e85ab87dd60c7). You can see that the value is not set to `0` even if you pass it.

Comment: The only thing I can think is that it has to do with the fact that you've set auto increment in your first line whereas my field is not yet set to auto increment. Possibly I need to set to auto increment first and then set the starting point. But I can't set to auto increment without the starting point as it says 'You already have a 1'

Comment: Yeah as I thought. Remove your auto increment in the first line and it will no longer give you an ID of 20

Comment: @JeremyRenner2: of course, you need to make the column `auto_increment` first, otherwise the setting does not apply... So: `alter table students modify studentID int auto_increment;`

Comment: But I can't do that as I mentioned above as I already have data in the table. I get the message:

Error Code: 1062. ALTER TABLE causes auto_increment resequencing, resulting in duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: OK, I had to remove the row which had a 0 id from being inserted before the auto increment.